# How to increase font size of particular substrings in UITextView?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I'm trying to have this representation in the iPhone app I'm building using Swift 4.2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuKN8.jpg

Currently, I'm creating the representation as an image and it's being displayed in a UIImageView. However, I would like to increase the size of a particular substring in the code than using images. I do not mind using frameworks.

I have tried using NSAttributedString but it is a cumbersome process defining it for every string (there are 12+ such strings)

Edit:

So I created the following class in **Swift 4.2, iOS 12**:

```
public class representations {

func plus1() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]{
    let plus1: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
    ]
    return plus1
}

func plus2() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]{
    let plus1: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 33)
    ]
    return plus1
}

func minus1() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]{
    let minus1: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    ]
    return minus1
}

func minus2() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]{
    let minus2: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    ]
    return minus2
}

func boldify() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]{
    let bold: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    ]
    return bold
}

func correct() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]{
    let correct: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.green
    ]
    return correct
}

func incorrect() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]{
    let incorrect: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
    ]
    return incorrect
}


}
```

And here's how the function call works:

```
for (innerKey,innerValue) in value["attributes"] as! [String: [String: [Int]]]{
    var i = 0
    let loc = innerValue["location"] as! [Int]
    let length = innerValue["length"] as! [Int]
    for location in loc {
    switch(innerKey){
         case "plus1" :
                    attributedString.addAttributes(rep.plus1(), range: NSRange(location: location-1, length: length[i]))
         case "plus2" :
                    attributedString.addAttributes(rep.plus2(), range: NSRange(location: location-1, length: length[i]))
         case "minus1" :
                    attributedString.addAttributes(rep.minus1(), range: NSRange(location: location-1, length: length[i]))
         case "minus2" :
                    attributedString.addAttributes(rep.minus2(), range: NSRange(location: location-1, length: length[i]))
         default:
                    print("default case")
        }
        i+=1

    }
}
```

All the data of where to add the attributes is stored in a dictionary:

```
        "attributes" : [
            "plus1" : [
                "location" : [32,34],
                "length" : [1,3]
            ],
            "plus2" : [
                "location" : [33],
                "length" : [1]
            ],
        ]
```

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q39pr.jpg)!

Comment: Coding is often a cumbersome process. If concatenating attributed strings is not an option then you're out them.

Answer (score 1):

NSAttributedString really is your only option here, as this format can contain multiple text formats. You could write a script which "scans" for certain words in your normal text, then for each character upgrade the font +1 size until it has reached the middle, then decrease again until it reached the default font again.